# Converting ascii to text

Tags: javascript, ascii

How do I take an ascii code and convert it into its character using JavaScript?  I'm in a nested loop and need to label each loop 1A, 2A, 1B, 2B, etc, and I would like to avoid hard coding every character using if statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```js
String.fromCharCode(ascii_value)
```

This is plain Javascript by the way. If you want to use hex numbers, convert them to decimal by using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
parseInt("ff", 16)
```

For example, this snippet takes the hex number **ff** and returns the character **ÿ**:

```js
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("ff", 16))
```